# Jaas session replication on JBoss 4.2.0

Tags: jboss, replication, jaas, authorization

I've looked the web through and through in the search of answer to my problem but with no result so I reckon that's the ultimate place when anybody can have a clue what the solution might be.

Long story short: we have a jsf web application running on JBoss 4.2.0 GA server. We are in the process of replicating the application to several servers which is generally a smooth ride with just one single exception: JAAS. We use Jaas as our security mechanism but can't get the Jaas session replicated. When load balancer switches user to different server, the user has to log on again (however the jsf session state is not lost, it's gets replicated with no problem). How can we get Jaas to replicate its session over several servers? Is it possible in a stright way?

Or do we have to tinker with programmatic authorisation, which in case of Tomcat, seems to be possible only by reflection?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look in cookies. Better to use some HTTP protocol sniffer.